# Breeze entities with typescript

Tags: knockout.js, typescript, breeze, single-page-application

I'm using Breeze + Typescript + Knockout for a Spa, and I'm facing the following problem:
when I create a new entity with EntityManager.createEntity, typescript doesn't let me use the observables that Breeze generates from metadata.
Typescript "sees" only the "entityAspect" and the "entityType" properties.
I'm using the type definitions of DefinitelyTyped.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You can create an interface for your type which extends `breeze.Entity`:

```
/// <reference path="breeze.d.ts" />
module model {
    export interface ResponsesItem extends breeze.Entity {
        ContentTypeID: string;
        Title: string;
        Description: string;
        EventDate: any;
        /* etc. */
    }
}
```

You can then cast your objects to this interface whenever you need to work with them in a typed way, such as the result of a query when loading from the server :

```
     private loadResponses(): void {
         this.dataservice.ListResponses()
            .then((data: { results: breeze.Entity[]; query: breeze.EntityQuery; XHR: XMLHttpRequest; }) => {
                var results: model.ResponsesItem[] = <model.ResponsesItem[]>data.results;
                // Do something with typed results array here.
         }).fail((error) => {
            this.handleDataError(error);
         });
      }
```

Comment: Thanks JcFx,
sounds good! Will try this out and report back :-)
PS: What if I have multiple models, sent by different Breeze queries?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking but yes - I have a separate method on my client-side dataservice for each type, so I know what I'm expecting from a particular call and can cast appropriately. Bear in mind that a property of an interface can be another interface, so you can have a structured, typed model. Also check out  Christoffer's useful T4 template to generate interfaces from your server-side classes: https://github.com/cskeppstedt/t4ts

Answer (score 2):

Check out my answer at [Breeze.js typed entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817230/breeze-js-typed-entities/16028385#16028385) wherein I hacked T4TS to spit out TS definitions that support Breeze.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knockout/knockout.d.ts

Functions you see on ko (e.g. observable etc) are the functions defined on KnockoutStatic interface because of this line:

```
declare var ko: KnockoutStatic;
```

Here is a snippet of this interface:

```
interface KnockoutStatic {
    utils: KnockoutUtils;
    memoization: KnockoutMemoization;
    bindingHandlers: KnockoutBindingHandlers;
    virtualElements: KnockoutVirtualElements;
    extenders: KnockoutExtenders;

    applyBindings(viewModel: any, rootNode?: any): void;
    applyBindingsToDescendants(viewModel: any, rootNode: any): void;
    applyBindingsToNode(node: Element, options: any, viewModel: any): void;

    subscribable: KnockoutSubscribableStatic;
    observable: KnockoutObservableStatic;
    computed: KnockoutComputedStatic;
    observableArray: KnockoutObservableArrayStatic;
    .....
```

So if you want new functions on ko you need to define new functions to the KnockoutStatic interface e.g.:

```
interface KnockoutStatic {
    yourFunc: KnockoutObservableStatic;
}
```

etc. Since interfaces are open ended you can declare various parts of the interface definition in multiple files.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hy, thanks for Your answer.
I'm nt sure this would solve my problem, which is TypeScript not being able to catch the dynamic nature of the Breeze Entities.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a page you can drop in your site to generate typescript interface definitions.  The page fetches the breeze metadata then iterates through all of the types and outputs a typescript interface declaration for each type.  The output of this page can then be pasted in any typescript file (*.ts) or typescript definition file (*.d.ts).  Enclose the results in a module declaration if you want to namespace the interfaces:  `declare module northwind { ... paste interfaces here...  }`.

Before using the page you'll need to make one edit:  change the entity manager's controller url from "api/northwind" to whatever your breeze controller's url is.

The generated interfaces have a dependency on the Knockout.js typescript definitions which you can grab here: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/knockout/

Using the northwind example from [learn.breezejs.com](http://learn.breezejs.com/), the output of this definitions generator page would be something like this:

```
export interface Employee extends breeze.Entity {
    FirstName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    LastName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
}
```

you could then execute a query using breeze and cast the results to an array of employees like this:

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('api/northwind');

var query = new breeze.EntityQuery()
    .from("Employees");

manager.executeQuery(query).then(data => {
    // ***cast the results to a strongly typed array of Employee***
    var employees = <Employee[]>data.results;
}).fail(e => {
    alert(e);  
});
```

below is the definitions generator page- add a new html file to your project named "definitions.html", run the project and navigate to the page.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Typescript Definition Generator</title>
    <style>
        code {
            white-space: pre;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.0.0/q.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/breezejs/1.4.4/breeze.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var entityManager = new breeze.EntityManager('api/northwind');
            entityManager.fetchMetadata()
                .then(function () {
                    var html = '',
                        types = entityManager.metadataStore.getEntityTypes(),
                        type,
                        i,
                        j,
                        property,
                        crlf = String.fromCharCode(13),
                        code = document.createElement('code'),
                        script = document.createElement('script');

                    function getJSType(metadataType) {
                        if (/(Int64)|(Int32)|(Int16)|(Byte)|(Decimal)|(Double)|(Single)|(number)/.test(metadataType))
                            return 'number';
                        else if (/(DateTime)|(DateTimeOffset)|(Time)|(Date)/.test(metadataType))
                            return 'Date';
                        else if (/(Boolean)/i.test(metadataType))
                            return 'boolean';
                        return 'string';
                    }

                    for (i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
                        // type declaration
                        var type = types[i];
                        html += 'export interface ' + type.shortName;

                        // base type
                        html += ' extends ';
                        if (type.hasOwnProperty('baseEntityType')) {
                            html += type.baseEntityType.shortName;
                        } else {
                            html += 'breeze.Entity';
                        }
                        html += ' {' + crlf;

                        // data properties
                        for (j = 0; j < type.dataProperties.length; j++) {
                            property = type.dataProperties[j];
                            if (type.baseEntityType && type.baseEntityType.dataProperties.filter(function (p) { return p.name === property.name; }).length > 0)
                                continue;
                            html += '    ' + property.name;
                            //if (property.isNullable)
                            //    html += '?';
                            html += ': KnockoutObservable&lt;';
                            html += getJSType(property.dataType.name);
                            html += '&gt;; //' + property.dataType.name + crlf;
                        }

                        // navigation properties
                        for (j = 0; j < type.navigationProperties.length; j++) {
                            property = type.navigationProperties[j];
                            if (type.baseEntityType && type.baseEntityType.navigationProperties.filter(function (p) { return p.name === property.name; }).length > 0)
                                continue;
                            html += '    ' + property.name;
                            //if (property.isNullable)
                            //    html += '?';
                            if (property.isScalar)
                                html += ': KnockoutObservable&lt;';
                            else
                                html += ': KnockoutObservableArray&lt;';
                            html += property.entityType.shortName;
                            html += '&gt;;' + crlf;
                        }

                        html += '}' + crlf + crlf;
                    }

                    code.innerHTML = html;

                    $(code).addClass('prettyprint');

                    document.body.appendChild(code);

                    script.setAttribute('src', '//google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js');
                    document.body.appendChild(script);
                })
                .fail(function (reason) {
                    alert(reason);
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```