# What is the equivalent of metadata helper for typescript?

Tags: typescript, breeze

I am developing a module using typescript and Sharepoint 2013 and need to extract data using REST services. I came across "Breeze" which makes things easier for me with its LINQ like syntax and lot of other advantages. however i got stuck at one point - i could not get an equivalent of metadata helper for typescript.

Do let me know in case anyone has already got a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for ".d.ts" definitions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375246/how-to-generate-typescript-interfaces-definitions-for-breeze-entities and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15560187/breeze-entities-with-typescript articles may be helpful for you.