# Can typescript compiler produce POCO .NET types/assembly?

Tags: c#, typescript

I'm getting into app development using knockout with MVC and EF and I'm looking at how adding TypeScript to the recipe might help me out.

I like the cleaner mechanism for authoring in the IDE but the missing thing seems to be the ability to reference the interfaces defined in typescript from other .NET assemblies.

Am I right that there's nothing stopping this from happening other than it hasn't been done?  I'm curious if there a demand for it or if I am looking at the problem domain in a way that others aren't.

The reason I see utility is because currently I have no way to define a given DTO in just one place.  I have to either author them separately in my C# View model and javascript/typescript or I have to use something like the knockout mapping plugin which is too much "magic" for my tastes.

**Note**: I'm not asking for arbitrary typescript to .NET conversion.  I'd just like typescript interfaces to produce usable .NET POCO types.

**Note2**: I just found http://typescript.codeplex.com/ which does what I'm asking in the opposite direction (from .NET to typescript) and this actually might be sufficient for the problem I'm expressing in this question.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but there's a bunch of definition files on https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: I am writing a Visual Studio extension called TypeSharp that does C# to TypeScript conversion. If you are interested in trying a pre release version email me at davemckeown@outlook.com - It will be an open source tool

Comment: thanks, I sent you an email..

Comment: The repo for the TypeSharp project is now public at http://github.com/davemckeown/TypeSharp

Answer (score 3):

There is a utility to convert C# classes into Typescript : http://type.litesolutions.net/

This way you can have your DTOs in one place i.e. C#. Available on Nuget and is open source on BitBucket so feel free to modify (even the code generation) and contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my answer at: [Breeze.js typed entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817230/breeze-js-typed-entities/16028385#16028385)

You can't use my solution in knockout templates, but it definitely helps on the TypeScript side.

Answer (score 0):

I approached this problem by serializing to JSON and back. Depending on your needs, the ease of this is worth is, and if your doc is complicated, its necessary.

Comment: Do you have the code up somewhere? I'm working on a general purpose TypeScript-to-.NET-wrapper compiler and am curious about other attempts.

Comment: Sorry, its closed-source for a company.

Answer (score 0):

> As of version 1.7, Bridge supports the generation of TypeScript
>   definitions for C# types. In this article, you learn how to instruct
>   the Bridge compiler to emit .d.ts alongside the matching .js files and
>   use them in a Visual Studio TypeScript project

http://bridge.net/docs/generate-typescript-definitions/

Answer (score 0):

> Typewriter is a free extension for Visual Studio that generates
>   TypeScript files from c# code files using TypeScript Templates.This
>   allows you to create fully typed TypeScript representations of server
>   side API, models, controllers, SignalR hubs etc. that automatically
>   updates when you make changes to your c# code.By doing this you get
>   TypeScript Intellisense and compile-time errors when the client- and
>   server side code differs. This speeds up your development pace and
>   increases the quality of your applications.

https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/