# How to generate typescript interfaces/definitions for breeze entities - follow up

Tags: breeze

This is a follow up to [How to generate typescript interfaces/definitions for breeze entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21375246/how-to-generate-typescript-interfaces-definitions-for-breeze-entities)

It was mentioned at the bottom that an official version was being worked on.  Was this every released?  Still in beta?  Either way, I would like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the typescript files here:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/breeze

and we do keep these up to date.

Comment: Hi Jay, Thank you, but I was looking for how to type data entities themselves, not the Type Definitions for breeze itself.  In other words, I would like a typed "contact" to work with on the client.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a cool utility to generate TS interfaces for your entities from metadata. Totally doable.

We don't have it and it is not coming from us soon as we have more urgent priorities. Have you tried Jeremy's technique (mentioned in that post)? I haven't yet.

Would you like to contribute such a thing? Feel free!

Comment: Yes, would love to help out.  You know I am a long time supporter of all things IdeaBlade. It took me a long time to make the jump from DevForce to Breeze, but now that I have seen the light, I am diving in. :)